# Elasticsearch-python - bulk helper API with refresh

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I need to index multiple documents in bulk with making them available to search as soon as possible. So, I want to use [refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/docs-refresh.html) in order to suffice this requirement.

I am currently using the code like this below. Taking example from [official site](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html)

```py
def gendata():
    mywords = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
    for word in mywords:
        yield {
            "_index": "mywords",
            "_type": "document",
            "doc": {"word": word},
        }

bulk(es, gendata())
```

I wish to attach a **refresh=true** to make it visible instantly.

Can you please help me know of this is possible with python bulk API?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `refresh` parameter:

```
bulk(es, gendata(), refresh="true")
```

The `bulk` function documentation does not mention this parameter, but it is described in the [`bulk` method documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.bulk).

Basically, the `bulk` method has a `refresh` parameter; available values are:

- "true"
- "wait_for"
- "false" (the default).

For more details, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40678914/4744341).

Comment: You can also use the python booleans `True` and `False` instead of the corresponding strings.