# OpenSearch index change not reflected in search

Tags: c#, opensearch, amazon-opensearch, open-search-server

When we delete an item form the cache and then immediate do a search the search does not reflect the recent deletion.

The search happens immediately after the index deletion or update.

How can I fix this?  I don't see an aws configuration setting that will ensure the index is updated fully before returning.

Comment: How many shards does your OpenSearch cluster have? Have you tried setting [wait_for_active_shards](https://opensearch.org/docs/2.4/api-reference/document-apis/delete-document/) to `'all'`?

Comment: Thanks, I finally figured out the syntax for that in the dotnet client, but it times out waiting.  

I added the wait on the dashboard, and I get the following error now:

    "type" : "unavailable_shards_exception",
    "reason" : "[invoices][2] Not enough active copies to meet shard count of [ALL] (have 1, needed 2). Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[invoices][2]] containing [delete {[invoices][306]}]]"

Comment: I fixed that by adding more to my server with more data nodes, however, the wait_for_active_shards = 'all' still does not return a search without that record (but it is gone if you query again in a second or two.  Any other ideas @cam

Comment: Actually, I got it fixed by adding ?refresh=wait_for to the query string.  
This article was helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40678914/98802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it fixed by adding the "?refresh=wait_for" on the query string.

like `DELETE /invoices/306?refresh=wait_for`

This is a link to the [ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40676324/98802) version of this problem here is a link to the [OpenSearch docs](https://opensearch.org/docs/2.5/api-reference/document-apis/delete-document/).  Pay attention to the refresh paramater.
and