# Wait for document creation operation in Elasticsearch. Refreshing the index seems not to solve

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm creating some documents in elasticsearch using parallel bulk, using a python client.
After running this command, I do a Index refresh. However, when I do a search on the same index, I sometimes still do not find the document...

I've looked at the documentation of the refresh query parameter, there's a wait_for parameter. It says that it waits for a refresh, but am I not doing a refresh, when I do a refresh?

1. What does this parameter actually does?
2. How can I wait until I'm sure that all documents will show up in the query?

Comment: The first answer to this post answers your question about when you should perform a refresh operation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676324/elasticsearch-updates-are-not-immediate-how-do-you-wait-for-elasticsearch-to-fi